# How to view PDF in Artbox?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, pdftk, acrobat-pro-dc

I have a PDF, which by default it displays the pages in Trimbox/Bleedbox sizes.

But if I "crop" something, clearly you can see that there is an Artbox outside.

How can I set the default display to be in "Artbox", so that I see everything?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display everything within the Artbox, set the Cropbox to the same as the Artbox (or to be more generous, to the Mediabox…).

Comment: How exactly can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Done. Easier than thought!